# How to insert data into one table which is coming from 2 different csv files using conditional split transformation?

Tags: ssis

I am having two 3 csv files 1 teacher and 2 students I have to insert teachers data into one table and students data who got more than 50 marks into one table from 2 csv files, please explain how to use conditional split transformation for those 2 students file to put the data into one table

Comment: In order to help show us your work/code

Comment: what have you tried? Can you load the data into the table without a conditional split yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you to use the Coniditional Split?  You need to combine the student flatfiles into one table, right?  If so, what you want to use is a **Merge Join** transformation.

[image]

You can read more about how to use the Merge Join, [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1322/merge-multiple-data-sources-with-sql-server-integration-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the question correctly. My assumptions:

1. Teacher is moved from CSV to a table 1 no conditions.
2. Student files (CSV) contain only unique records.
3. Records where student achieved score greater or equal to 50 are inserted into a table 2.

If the above assumptions are correct. The simplest way will be to use a loop container to loop through the students file, and have one workflow which does as follows:

- Reads student file
- Passes the file to the conditional split
- Writes to the destination table

Conditional split task allows one to configure the conditions and outputs on those conditions.

If the file contains the column called StudentScore, then in the conditional split the first condition should be set as in the attached screen, please note that because the StudentScore is set to a string in the source file it has to be converted to the integer hence (DT_I4), if it is set to be an integer in the source file this conversion is redundant.

I also have given an output a name StudentScore, this output then will be linked to the destination file. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I have forgotten to add one more assumption structure of both student files is the same.